# Sign multiple PDFs without calling login for each file

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pkcs#11

When I will sign multiple PDF's I have one problem.

My code is:

```
public void signPDF(X509Certificate cert, List<File> fInl, List<File> fOutl,
                    PrivateKey key)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
                   NoSuchProviderException, InvalidParameterSpecException,
                   DocumentException, InvalidKeyException,
                   SignatureException, KeyStoreException,
                   CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

    Certificate[] cc = new Certificate []{cert};

    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<fInl.size();i++){
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fInl.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(fOutl.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, outputFile, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, null);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.setDate(new PdfDate(cal));
        dic.setName(PdfPKCS7.getSubjectFields((X509Certificate)cc[0]).getField("CN"));
        sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
        sap.setLayer2Text("Digitally signed by "+ dic.get(PdfName.NAME) +"\n\nDate: " + cal.getTime().toString());

        HashMap<PdfName,Object> exc = new HashMap<PdfName,Object>();
        exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(0x2502));
        sap.preClose(exc);

        PdfPKCS7 pk7 = new PdfPKCS7(key, cc, null, "SHA1", null, false);
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
        int n;
        InputStream inp = sap.getRangeStream();

        while ((n = inp.read(buf)) > 0) {
            messageDigest.update(buf, 0, n);
        }

        byte hash[] = messageDigest.digest();
        byte sh[] = pk7.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal);
        pk7.update(sh, 0, sh.length);

        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
        byte sg[] = pk7.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal);
        byte out[] = new byte[0x2500 / 2];

        System.arraycopy(sg, 0, out, 0, sg.length);
        dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(out).setHexWriting(true));
        sap.close(dic2);
    }
}
```

And it works, but calls "login token" for each file.

In this line `byte sh[] = pk7.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal);` the login of certificate installed is always called and I want to call it only once.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by _"login token"_ and _"the login of certificate installed is always called"_? Do you mean the password to access your keystore you have to enter multiple times?

Comment: Hmm... it looks like you're using a mighty old version of iText. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because you have that line in the for loop. So the line will be executed for each iteration.

To solve this, you have to first authenticate and then loop the results.

Hope it helps! 
Keep on coding 
Ares.